# JAXB inheritance conflict - Re-annotating on sub-classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I currently have this environment on my project:

```
public abstract class Foo {

   private List<Thing> things;

   public List<Thing> getThings() { return this.things; }
}

public abstract class Bar extends Foo {


   @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "first", type = First.class)})
   public List<Thing> getThings() { return super.getThings(); }

}

public class Bobar extends Bar {

   @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "second", type = Second.class)})
   public List<Thing> getThings() { return super.getThings(); }

}
```

For the following XML document

```
<bobar>
   <first>blablabla</first>
   <second>blublublu</second>
</bobar>
```

When I do

```
context = JAXBContext.newInstance("the.package.structure");
unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Bar object = (Bar) unmarshaller.unmarshal("path-to-xml-document");
```

The Bar `object` only has one element in the collection, not 2. The `First` element is completly lost, when I try to do `object.getThings()`, its size is 1 and the only object inside the collection is an instance of `Second`. Can someone help me how can I achieve to get both objects in the collection? And if that's not possible, how can I achieve something similar to this?

The reason I'm doing this is that (in my project logic) every `Bobar`s things collection has a `First` in its collection, but not every `Bar` has a `Second` in its collection, and `Foo` is a generic class.

### Edit:

When I change the order in my XML document, the output is different.

```
<bobar>
   <second>blablabla</second>
   <first>blublublu</first>
</bobar>
```

In this scenario, I get only an instance of `First` in the collection, and `Second` is lost. And changing the scenario more, I get interesting results:

```
public abstract class Foo {

   private List<Thing> things;

   public List<Thing> getThings() { return this.things; }
}

public abstract class Bar extends Foo {


   @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "first", type = First.class), @XmlElement(name = "third, type = Third.class)})
   public List<Thing> getThings() { return super.getThings(); }

}

public class Bobar extends Bar {

   @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "second", type = Second.class)})
   public List<Thing> getThings() { return super.getThings(); }

}
```

If I do

```
<bobar>
   <third>bliblibli</third>
   <second>blablabla</second>
   <first>blublublu</first>
</bobar>
```

In theory, I think this shouldn't be validated against the XML Schema generated by that, as the order here is not correct. But besides that, in such scenario, I get `Second` and `First`, the `Third` is lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to annotate a property on a super type, and have a sub try incrementally add to that mapping.  Below is a way you could support all the use cases that you are after.  One thing to be cautious of is that all levels in the object hierarchy would support the same set of elements.  You would need to use a external means of validation to restrict the desired values.

If `Thing` is a class not an interface, and `First` and `Second` extend `Thing` then you may be interested in using `@XmlElementRef` instead of `@XmlElements` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html).  It will offer you more flexibility, at the cost of some validation (hard to restrict the set of valid values).

**Bar**

We will annotate the `Bar` with `@XmlTransient` so that the JAXB implementation doesn't process it.

```
package forum11698160;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlTransient
public abstract class Bar extends Foo {

    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return super.getThings();
    }

}
```

**Bobar**

`@XmlElementRef` corresponds to the concept of substitution groups in XML schema.  The values matching the property will be based on `@XmlRootElement` declarations.

```
package forum11698160;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Bobar extends Bar {

    @XmlElementRef
    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return super.getThings();
    }

}
```

**Thing**

As JAXB implementations can not use reflection to find all the subclasses of a type, we can use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to help out.  If you don't use this annotation then you will need to include all the subtypes when bootstrapping the `JAXBContext`.

```
package forum11698160;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({First.class, Second.class})
public class Thing {

}
```

**First**

We will need to annotate `First` with  `@XmlRootElement`:

```
package forum11698160;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class First extends Thing {

}
```

**Second**

`Second` will also need to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`:

```
package forum11698160;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Second extends Thing {

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11698160;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bobar.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11698160/input.xml");
        Bobar bobar =  (Bobar) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(bobar, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bobar>
    <first/>
    <second/>
</bobar>
```

---

**OTHER FILES**

Below are the other files you need to run this example:

**Foo**

```
package forum11698160;

import java.util.*;

public abstract class Foo {

    private List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();

    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return this.things;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, I see that I just can't do what I wanted to do. I just can't understand why it doesn't work the way it is suposed to work. What I wanted to do is to add more possibilities to the list of things. I can't understand why if I do an extension of `Bobar`, let's call it `Fobar`, and annotate `getThings` with `@XmlElements`, the list doesn't contain both elements from `Bobar` and `Fobar`, as in the XML Schema, all those attributes would show up, as it's an extension. The schema is generated correctly, the thing is when the JAXB unmarshals, this happens. I'm so sad, really really sad =\

Comment: In the XML Schema, I have `Fobar` as a complexType, with a complexContent and with `Bobar` as extension base. `Fobar` would has elements `Third` in the sequence, and `Bobar` has elements `First` and `Second`. I thought that JAXB instantiates a list for `Bobar` and puts the elements inside, and then instantiates another for `Fobar` and put the elements, But if you change the order of the elements, some weird things happens. I guess I'll have to live with that then. Thank you for your answers and your time!

Answer (score 2):

Below is how you could map this use case by leveraging `@XmlTransient`:

**Bobar**

You can't extend mappings in the subclasses, so you need to be sure when you do an `@XmlElements` mapping you do everything (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html).

```
package forum11698160;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Bobar extends Bar {

    @XmlElements({ 
        @XmlElement(name = "first", type = First.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "second", type = Second.class)
    })
    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return super.getThings();
    }

}
```

**Bar**

You also can't override inherited properties.  So we will need to use `@XmlTransient` at the type level to indicate that we don't want our JAXB implementation to process the super type (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).

```
package forum11698160;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlTransient
public abstract class Bar extends Foo {

    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return super.getThings();
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The following demo code can be used to demonstrate that everything works:

```
package forum11698160;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bobar.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11698160/input.xml");
        Bobar bobar =  (Bobar) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(bobar, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bobar>
   <first/>
   <second/>
</bobar>
```

---

**OTHER FILES**

Below are the other files you need to run this example:

**Foo**

```
package forum11698160;

import java.util.*;

public abstract class Foo {

    private List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();

    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return this.things;
    }

}
```

**Thing**

```
package forum11698160;

public interface Thing {

}
```

**First**

```
package forum11698160;

public class First implements Thing {

}
```

**Second**

```
package forum11698160;

public class Second implements Thing {

}
```

Comment: That approach I know and I'm using it, but if I wanted to extend `Bobar`, and add a new element to the list of possible things, is there any way I could do that?

Comment: @SHiRKiT - I have added a second answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11800496/383861).  It uses `@XmlElementRef` which will offer you more flexibility at the expense of less validation.

Comment: @blaise-doughan is it possible to generate above mapping from an xsd and necessary binding files? or can it be done manually ?