# Override JAXB annotation in derived class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a base class:

```
abstract public class BaseClass {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElementRef
    protected List<boolean> myBools = new LinkedList<boolean>();

    @Override
    public List<boolean> getBools() {
        return myBools;
    }

    @Override
    public void addBool(boolean newBool) {
        myBools.add(newBool);
    }

}
```

And a derived class:

```
public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {

     // other stuff
}
```

Is there a way to override the XML annotation of myBool in the derived class, so that e.g. myBool is not marshalled to XML? e.g. something like:

```
public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {

    @XmlTransient
    private boolean myBool;

}
```

I've seen solutions to this problem for class methods e.g. here: [JAXB inheritance conflict - Re-annotating on sub-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698160/jaxb-inheritance-conflict-re-annotating-on-sub-classes), but not to members.

Comment: Is this the only way this is annotated, or are there also getters/setters?

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my questions to more accurately reflect what the annotations are. You can see there is a getter and a (sort of) setter.